# Fetching product details on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover, detailsview

I want to integrate a function into my website, whereby if a user hovers their mouse on the name of a product, a box appears which will show the details of this product. For this I would preferably like to use either CSS or Javascript, I am not really sure how I would go about doing this though. Can anyone offer me some guidance please? I am currently using the JQuery UI with essentially the same code as the shopping cart code seen here :

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart

Thnk you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be fancy and use jquery, here is a [list of popup plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/popup) that you can browse.

If the product information isn't too complicated I would suggest using CSS as it is simpler.  Also, you probably want to have the data already loaded, so the user doesn't have to wait a round trip to your server every time they mouse over a product. [Here](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/) is a simple CSS popup tutorial.